# How to extract elements from an array of objects that contains a subtring - Javascript and Angular 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I am trying to take the elements on an array that contains a substring.
For example:

```
 myArray = [{name: "Pablo Ramon", lastName: "Garcia"}, {name: "Ernesto", lastName: "Salgado"}]
```

And giving a string to look for `str = "Ra"`, I would like to create a new array only with `{name: "Pablo Ramon", lastName: "Garcia"}` after applying the filter.

If I am not wrong this is possible using a `map` but I do not know how to do it.

**EDIT**

My current structure is:
**Object**

```
export class Car{
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

**From the service**

```
  betList: any;
```

The error that I get after using the next command is:

*Command 1*

```
 this.betList = this.betList.filter(o =>
   Object.values(o).some(s => s.includes(title))
 );
```

*Command 2*

```
this.betList = this.betList.filter(o =>
   Object.values(o).some(s => s.indexOf(title) >= 0)
);
```

*Error*

> ```
> Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.filter()` in simple way:

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Pablo Ramon",
  lastName: "Garcia"
}, {
  name: "Ernesto",
  lastName: "Salgado"
}];
var result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.includes("Ra")));

console.log(result);
```

Another solution without `.includes()`:

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Pablo Ramon",
  lastName: "Garcia"
}, {
  name: "Ernesto",
  lastName: "Salgado"
}];
var result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.indexOf("Ra") >= 0 ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The error that I get using that is "Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}'."

Comment: @Mario Are you using some _tool_ like Internet Er. Explorer? 

Comment: @Mario Oh... Okay, which browser?

Comment: I am using Chrome but I guess it is not the problem since the error is even shown in Visual Studio

Comment: Looks like the browser that does the interpretation doesn't know the [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: @Mario Are you able to execute the snippet at least? Click on Run Code Snippet and tell me?

Comment: @Mario Let's try another solution.

Comment: just use `data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.indexOf("Ra") >=0 ));`

Comment: @Mario Yea, try Akrion's suggestion... I was typing that... ^

Comment: I guess that the problem is that I have another structure of object but from my point of view it should be the same that the one I have posted in the question

Comment: I have updated my question. I m gonna mark your answer as correct since it was correct, but if you have any idea about what s going on checking the update it would be helpful

Comment: @Mario I did add another section in my answer. Did you have a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183654/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-purushothaman-and-mario).

Answer (score 1):

You can filter array using `.filter()` and String's `.includes()` methods:

```js
let data = [{name: "Pablo Ramon", lastName: "Garcia"}, {name: "Ernesto", lastName: "Salgado"}];

let str = 'Ra';

let result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.includes(str)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The error that I get using that is "Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}'."

Answer (score 0):

```
[{name: "Pablo Ramon", lastName: "Garcia"}, {name: "Ernesto", lastName: "Salgado"}]
.filter (p => p.name.includes ('Ra'))

//{name: "Pablo Ramon", lastName: "Garcia"}
```